# Facebook Analytics does not show me data

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

yesterday I Include the Facebook SDK for JavaScript in my Web Page (here is the code  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/quickstart-list/web with the ID of my application )

anyway, I want to see some data on the panel, but it does not show me anything. Just this default message: "Once you start logging events, this overview will give you a summary of how people are using your app or website. You'll be able to see data like sessions, active users, purchases, demographics and more."

see a print screen here  https://snag.gy/9tZkT7.jpg

I believe it about Creating events, I don'w know how to do this. Can anyone help me step by step?

Comment: did you debug your code? does it hit the facebook server? did you check out event debugging? did you wait "up to 20min"?

Comment: yes, I wait 24 hours :) This is my code that I copy in all of my pages   https://ideone.com/Z6A6tD

I don't know about debugging code or events. can you be more specific ?

Comment: you need to get familiar with browser dev tools, they are very important for a developer.

Comment: about event debugging: that is explained in the link of your answer.  don´t just copy code, read ALL the information about it in the docs and make sure you understand every single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.init({
   appId      : '{214793561804710}',
   xfbml      : true,
   version    : 'v3.0'
});
```

This is wrong, do not use the brackets from the docs. The Id is just a string:

```
FB.init({
   appId      : '214793561804710',
   xfbml      : true,
   version    : 'v3.0'
});
```

After changing that and hitting your URL, wait 20min and check out `Activity > Event Debugging` in the App Settings.

Comment: Now I can see something, maybe I should create a facebook page for all of my html pages? Seems that if I test a single page, analitycs shows me some data. But if I test my aplication (with the id in all the pages) is not shows me anything.

Comment: no, you do not need any facebook page...so does it work now, or not? again, you have to give it some time.

Comment: no, it doesn't work when I select to view "My Application" . So, in analytics I have to choose what to see, between pages and application. If I choose my application, it does not show my any data. But if I choose my personal page or other pages it shows me data.

Comment: did you check out the event debugging too, as i suggested in my answer?

Comment: hello, yes, NOW it's working. But after 24 hours, not 20 min. Thank you very much :)